# Did Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) ever contract temporary marriage (Mut'ah)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, source-identification, nikah-al-mutah, ahmadiyyah

I heard from an Ahmadi (sect) person that once the prophet went to a village. His followers told him there is a really pretty woman who lives here. The prophet contracted Mut'ah marriage with her for the night and left the next day. He said it was common in those days in Islam.

My question is:  Did Prophet Muhammad (Peace be upon him) ever contract Muta'h (temporary) marriage? Is the above story true?

Answer (score 4):

According to Shia Islam there is no proved evidence that show prophet himself did Mutah.

But please note when permission of an action is proved by Quran or authentic hadith there is no need for evidence that prophet or Ahl ul-Bayt practiced it and the evidence from Quran or Haith is enough to it be considered permitted.

There is a verse in Quran and many hadith in Shia Hadith books and some hadith in sunni Hadith books proving prophet permitted Mutah to sahaba and sahaba practiced Mutah. so there is enough proof for considering Mutah Halal even if no evidence is found prophet himself did or not.

**References:**

[Temporary Marriage in Islamic Law](http://www.al-islam.org/al-serat/muta/)

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/4634  (you can use google translate to read.)

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/915 (containing many evidence from sunni books)

Comment: it is interesting that the prophet *had to do* some of the things *himself* in order to allow it for others, as in the case of marrying his adopted son's wife. After that marriage, adoption was prohibited in Islam.

Comment: Many people call Mutah a "virtuous deed" BUT unfortunately the prophet(pbuh) didnt get blessings from this virtuous deed?

Comment: @islam101 talk clear. I do not know who call it virtuous deed. the answer is clear. we have no historical evidence for it. but this does not mean he really did not. our history is from 1400 years ago. many history books burnt and destroyed in history. also mutah has terms and is for some special cases and not for lust of men. it is possible prophet did not have any need to use it. also verse of Quran is clear about Mutah.

Comment: @Ahmadi I am thinking the prophet definitely did it. We just do not have references for it (as of now).

Answer (score 3):

In both **Shia** and **Sunni** sources, there is **no evidence** that shows the prophet did practice the Muta'ah marriage when it was considered permissible to do so.

However, according to **sunnis**. The prophet **prohibited** the mutah marriage after wining the war of khebar. While according to **shia** sources, Muta'ah marriage is still **permissible**.

***For more Information about Mutah marriage:***

1. **Sunni**:

   - **Hadith sources**: [Why did Umar (RA) forbid Mutah (temporary marriage) after the death of the prophet?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13283/why-did-umar-ra-forbid-mutah-temporary-marriage-after-the-death-of-the-proph)
   - **Quran Sources:** [Has mu'tah been forbidden via the Quran? (Sunni view)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7601/has-mutah-been-forbidden-via-the-quran-sunni-view)
2. **Shia**: [Why do Shi'as allow mut'ah marriage?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/570/why-do-shias-allow-mutah-marriage)