# Is all revelation (wahy) in the Quran?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, revelation

As all Muslims believe, the Quran was reveled by God to the prophet Muhammed (SAW), and this is what we define as devine revelation.
*Furthermore I will use the word **wahy** as a synonym to "devine revelation to the Prophet Muhammed".*

We believe this is true:
The whole QURAN is wahy.

**Does that mean that ALL wahy is in the Quran?** 
(Excluding [abrogated](https://quran.com/2/106) verses)
 *As a logical example; All lions are cats, whereas not all cats are lions.*

- If the answer is NO, then what makes some wahy to be part of the Quran and other not (excluding abrogated verses)?
- If the answer is YES, then how does one explain hadiths like this:
  *(If **all** wahy was in the Quran, then this would be expected to be there too.)*

  > Allah revealed to me that we should be humble amongst ourselves and none should show pride upon the others ...  ‏إن الله تعالى أوحى إلي أن
  >   [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/53/79)

Answer the bold question, then one of the sub questions.
If possible, provide references.

---

EDIT:
This might be a duplicate of the question: "[Does the Quran contain all of Allah's revelations? (Sunni view)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7603/15201)", but as my question includes some sub questions which aren't included in the other question or addressed in the answers, therefore I do not consider it as duplicate. Also I am not only looking for the Sunni view (i don't think there is a difference anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Not all wahy is in Quran . Quran is reserved in the book (Mushaf) , while other wahy , like Hadith, and Hadith Qudsi , are found in Sunna books.
https://islamqa.info/en/77243

َQuran is known by the prophet, and is taught by him to his companions. Some of them memorized it, and some of them wrote it, (as Quran not Hadith).   https://islamqa.info/en/22394

Quran was being recited once each year in Ramdan , by the prophet -may Allah give peace and blessings upon him- to the Angel Jibril, and he would recite it back to the prophet. The last year, they recited it twice. https://islamqa.info/en/12658

**Added**:

In the qudsi hadith : according to some scholars , The content and the meanings are from Allah but the words are the prophet's , while in the Quran , it is the words of Allah.

and the style and the language wordings , differs distinctly between the two .

so , you can not pray reading the Qudsi hadith in the prayer (salat).

see

https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/72798

https://islamqa.info/ar/136658

Comment: Thanks for answering. However your answer does not answer the sub questions which are important. It is already understood that not all wahy is in the Qur'an. The sub questions are of more importance

Comment: if you could rephrase the sub-question

Comment: In your case my sub question is "If not all wahy is in the quran, then what makes some wahy to be part of the Quran and other not (excluding abrogated verses"? I.e what is qualifying a verse to be in the Qur'an but not a qudsi hadith for instance when it's clear that the hadith contains "Allah revealed to me..."

Comment: In the qudsi hadith : The content and the meanings are from Allah but the words are the prophet's , while in the Quran , it is the words of Allah.

Comment: Alright! Please are that to your answer with some further details and explanations