# Did Shia imams or their wives practice mutah?

Tags: shiism, nikah-al-mutah

Shia allow mutah marriages.

[Why do Shi'as allow mut'ah marriage?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/570/why-do-shias-allow-mutah-marriage).

9th to 11th imam only, first 8 imams are also imams for Sunnis so i reject mutah on their part.

Answer (score 1):

```
                             بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

Firstly, it order to elucidate the issue, of note, **if a practice (such as Mut’ah and so forth) is Mobah/permissible, but there doesn’t seem to be the necessity of it to be done by Imams or …**

Secondly, in regards to its performance by Imams of Shia Islam: there are narrations that e.g. Imam Ali (a.s.) had temporary marriage to a woman. Meanwhile, according to existing evidences, it can be concluded that in all probability, Imam Ali (peace be upon him) did mut’ah during his Caliphate time, hence such narration would be regarded as a reason for practical revival of Mut’ah.

In the meantime, of note:

> All the Sahabah – including Abu Bakr and ‘Umar - considered mut’ah to
>   be halal throughout the lifetime of the Prophet, and throughout the
>   rule of Abu Bakr. For most of the era of ‘Umar, all the Sahabah
>   generally affirmed the permissibility of mut’ah. However, at the end
>   of his caliphate, he made it haram; and that changed everything. The
>   generality of the Sahabah obeyed him; and only a handful remained
>   steadfast in affirming the permissibility of temporary marriage. Some
>   of the Tabi’in also proclaimed it halal. However, the number of the
>   pro-mut’ah elements continued to dwindle among the Ahl al-Sunnah,
>   until none – or almost none - accepted it anymore. The Shi’is, on
>   their part, have remained unshakable and unyielding on the
>   permissibility of temporary marriage – from the time of the Messenger
>   till this very day of ours.

To pursue the entire text, kindly refer to the source(s) of the response.

---

**Sources:**

- https://www.al-islam.org/nikah-al-mutah-zina-or-sunnah-toyib-olawuyi
  and [this](https://www.al-islam.org/nikah-al-mutah-zina-or-sunnah-toyib-olawuyi/1-mutah-quran)
- [This sourse](https://www.al-islam.org/nikah-al-mutah-zina-or-sunnah-toyib-olawuyi/8-sunni-athar-misused-about-mutah) and
  http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa4634 and [this](http://%20http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa3775#)